# Forwading UDP packet without ip change

Tags: java, networking

I am working to send 1 UDP packet to from 1 computer and forward it to multiple host. I am using the following codes to receive however i can use `DatagramPacket` to send out the packet as it will modify the source ip.

Is there a way or tools that allows me to do so ? I am using a windows env. Thanks.

```
public class app{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, SocketException, IOException  {
        // TODO code application logic here
        byte[] buffer = {10,23,12,31,43,32,24};
        byte [] IP={-64,-88,1,106};
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(IP);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                buffer, buffer.length, address, 57
                );
        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        datagramSocket.send(packet);
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use IP Multicasting as an alternative?

Comment: @Mike i do not have a router or switch anyway to emulate a router/switch with a server ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to do in java, but if you somehow make it (jni) -you will face with more difficlut problem: what you try to do is ip-spoofing and any responseble internet-provider or hoster will block packets with forged ip-addresses.

Consider use of multicast or dont try to forge source ip of packets you send.